# Adding more than one swipeGestures not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboard

I have three views,

```
View1 <-- View2 --> View3
```

Now View2 on `leftSWipeGesture` will send me to VIew3 while on right Gesture send to View1

My problem is, `LeftGesture` is working fine But not right gesture. I am using push Segue on both

Here is my Code

```
- (void) screenSwiped
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tourSegue1" sender:self];

}

- (void) screenSwipedRight
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tourSegue2" sender:self];

}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenSwiped)];
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];



UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];


    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view structure you present at the start of your post is slightly misleading.  From that little diagram it appears that you're already in View 2, and going to View 1 should be a "popViewController" if you're in a navigation controller.

So firstly - please verify this information and make sure you don't need to "popViewController" instead of performWithSequeIdentifier (because it doesn't work going backwards like that).

Comment: look, i came from View1 to View2 using SwipeGestureRecognize UI. No navigation. My only way to go back to View 1 is to Go to view3 First and from View3 call a function to go back to View1. But I can't even go to View3. If you have better solution kindly tell me

Comment: can u tell me how to do popviewcontroller. Again I am not doing navigationController

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; But that's if you're using a navigationController.  If you're using seques then more than likely you're using navigationController whether defined in code or using Storyboards.

Comment: damn, yes I am using navigation. Sorry i thought of something else. Cool thanks mate it worked